# How to lookup screen-bounded tile indices in a rotated tilemap?

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, tile, bounds, culling

Normally, an Axis-aligned (rotation = 0) tilemap is easy to iterate through the visible tiles on the screen.

But how do you "cull" or filter the tile indexes when the entire tilemap is rotated?

[image]

**NOTE**: This is for improving a tile-rendering class in ActionScript 3.0 (in [Genome2D](http://blog.flash-core.com/)), but answers in other computer languages could just as well be applicable! :)

Comment: I'm not pretty sure what you exactly need, as 'cull', 'filter' and 'look-up' are extremely different things. Anyways, seems like a matrix would do all kind of work, as it will rotate and modify your input values (x,y).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to DO with each of the tiles, so I'll assume you want to find which ones to render and which ones not to.

[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29)

You can try to set up a dummy object on the screen and do this:

```
For each tile in tilemap
    if (dummyScreenObj.hitTestObject(tile))
        tile.visible = true
    else
        tile.visible = false
```

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid checking each invididual tiles. What I'm after is a way to set boundaries for an outer and inner for-loop (like you would normally use for an axis-aligned oriented tilemap), but that would iterate on sloped / scaled tiles as well. For example, instead of using `for(var c=columnStart; c<=columnEnd; c++)` and `for(var r=rowStart; r<=rowEnd; r++)`, it would iterate `for(var sc=slopedColumnStart; sc<=slopedColumnEnd; sc++)` and `for(var sr=slopedRowStart; sr<=slopedRowEnd; sr++)`, but would obviously require some math to figure out the tile-indexes. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I'm not so sure your goal is attainable. For your example, each row has a different number. This will always change depending on the rotation as well.

For example, now you have a row 2 long, followed by 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5.

Comment: If you don't want to go through the actual tiles individually, you could create a whole dummy copy of empty mc's mapped to the real tiles and test against those.